# jquery ui draggable deaccelerate on stop

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

i am using jquery ui draggable do drag a div around. whats the best way to smoothly ease out the drag after the drag stopped?
assuming the drag stopped abruptly.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing draggables with easing might work for you. This is a simplified solution from my answer to a previous thread, which was more specific:

[JQuery draggable with ease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398854/jquery-draggable-with-ease)

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px solid silver;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        helper: function(){
            // Create an invisible div as the helper. It will move and
            // follow the cursor as usual.
            return $('<div></div>').css('opacity',0);
        },
        drag: function(event, ui){
            // During dragging, animate the original object to
            // follow the invisible helper with custom easing.
            var p = ui.helper.position();
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: p.top,
                left: p.left
            },1000,'easeOutCirc');
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NJwER/26/

Comment: `position: relative;` in css was crucial, took a while to catch that!

Comment: Great solution - simple, understandable, and effective.