# Jquery drag and drop - ease

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add smooth or animate for jquery drag & drop?

Here's my code:

```
<!-- Drag and Drop -->  
     $("#sortable-left, #sortable-right").sortable({
         connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
         receive: function(e,ui){
         }
     });

     $("#sortable-right").on("click", "li a", function (){       
         $(this).closest('li').remove();        
     });

    $("#sortable-right").on("click", ".drop-close", function(){
        $("ul#sortable-left").append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"> <strong>'+$(this).parents("li").find("strong").text()+'</strong><div class="ui-plus-desc"> <a class="drop-close" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove">                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><span>at 11:47, 21 June 2014</span><span>by Mark Antany</span></div></li>');
    });
    <!-- Drag and Drop -->
```

Comment: You can't / shouldn't smoothen the drag operation. Do you mean the drop operation should be animated?

Comment: Yes. like that only...

is this possible above mentioned my code?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398854/jquery-draggable-with-ease

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but the below might work
When you click on the item to be dropped make its position:fixed and then ondrag change its position offset to the mouse pointers position

Comment: no. my drag and drop is working fine. i need just animate for drag-able. is this posssible?

Comment: i am talking about animate itself. <br/>
From your question i understand when your drag and drop you want the dragged item to smoothly follow the mouse? If that is the case will what i have told above work?<br/>
Changing the position:fixed does not make it bound to the common flow and changing its offset to the mouse pointers position will make the draggable item to move to the location where the mouse pointer is. On drop when you change the item position and insert it into drop container, it should look fine