# How can I add momentum / inertia to a drag using CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, html, translate, momentum

I am trying to add a momentum / inertia effect to a zoomed image drag (like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/529KH/) or just like iOs does it) and I'm having a tough time with it.

I've been struggling with this for a while and found some helpful resources (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443526/jquery-ui-drag-easing-inertia)) but most of the solutions involve jQuery and I would prefer to stick to plain javascript, no frameworks involved.

I'm working on a HTML5 / CSS3 zoom image code, with all the standard features: double-tap zoom, pinch zooming, dragging, panning, etc. and everything is done using CSS3's transform translation, combined with the scaling. Ex.

```
transform: translate(100px, 100px);
transition: 100ms;
```

I looked at how others are doing it and it involves consecutive animations of the left/right properties, with decreasing duration / distance, to create a sort of ease-in effect.

I tried to recreate it using translations, using a sort of recursive function (you can see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LGxBL/3/) (works with webkit browsers), please ignore the coding style, it was not meant to be best practice, just a demo). In this case, the animation is not fluid it all, the consecutive translations do not connect.

I have a somewhat basic understanding of the principle and I did take a look at some algorithms available online but I just can't figure out how can I achieve this using css translations.

The first part of the dragging, done on mousemove/touchmove moves the image with the cursor/finger but the continuing translation after the end is not... continuous, it's like a separate animation after the first one and doesn't resemble a natural momentum / inertia effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is using `animation-timing-function:`, which I believe currently requires vendor prefixes. You have a choice of using `ease-in`, `ease-out`, `ease-in-out`, or `cubic-bezier`. The latter uses the visualization of a function in 2D space; it's easier to configure that one using a generator. My personal favorite is [Ceaser](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).

Comment: Yes, I looked at Ceaser before and it's a very nice tool. But as far as I know ease-in is already the default option for the animation. The problem I have it's with combining sequential transformations. I have one translation during the actual drag and when I try to apply another one (or more) after it ends, the result is not fluid

Comment: This seems complicated. I'll do a bit of research and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is indeed complicated, I've been trying to solve this quite some time now and every solution I found involved jQuery and/or animating the left/right values. It's hard to believe no one tried to do this before with HTML5

Comment: Indeed. It's a bit soon to presume, but it doesn't look like this question's taking off. Could I recommend that you ask on alternative web development fora, like [Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com)?

Comment: I will give it a try but I think it's too soon. I'll probably wait until tomorrow

Comment: Trust me, it's never too soon. Daniweb generally isn't as dynamic a community as StackOverflow, so it takes longer to get answers, but 99% of the time, your question gets answered within a week of posting a competently asked, interesting question (yours is both).

Answer (score 10):

I managed to find something helpful in the end, it is still a work in progress but the results look promising.

The starting point was [this post](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/10/flick-list-with-its-momentum-scrolling-and-deceleration.html) made by Aryia Hidayat and in particular his [Kinetic Scroll](http://ariya.github.com/js/kinetic/), as well as a [post made by Joe Hewitt](http://joehewitt.com/2011/10/05/fast-animation-with-ios-webkit). Also, [this older version](http://gitorious.org/ofi-labs/x2/commit/8ccb334f) of his code seemed easier to understand and grasp the basic concept, even though the most recent should be better.

Basically, instead of connecting various translations with a non-null duration and synchronize their timing and acceleration, this method uses a large number of 0-duration translations, called very often.

Comment: Care to elaborate what "crap" is meant above?