# Inertia/Air pressure to swing/rotate a div when it's moved/dragged

Tags: javascript, physics, drag, mousemove

I've spent the last 6 hours trying to find an answer to my question but without any luck.

I have some div's that are draggable on my website. While I'm dragging them, I want a realistic effect, like there is an air pressure and they are pushed a bit, so they will swing a little when they are being dragged.

An example image of how the effect should work, can be seen here: [The inertia acceleration effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZX7S.jpg) (don't know what the effect is called)

I have googled these words in many different combinations "Javascript, acceleration, inertia, swing, physics, rotate, move, air pressure, friction, dangle" without finding anything to help me.

Though, I found a kind of similar effect on this JSFiddle[ 1 ] (link below). I also came across the Google Gravity[ 2 ] (link below), which have the effect i want to achieve, when you drag an element and move your mouse to the side.

[ 1 ] JSFiddle i found: www.jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/150/

[ 2 ] Google Gravity: www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google-gravity/

I've tried to create the effect by myself here:

```
var fn = {
    activeElm : null,
    pos : {},
    transPos : {},
    startPos : null,
    moveSteps : new Array(15),

    init : function(){
        var self = this;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){self.handleStart.call(self, e);});
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){self.handleMove.call(self, e);});
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){self.handleStop.call(self, e);});
    },
    handleStart : function(e){
        if(fn.hasClass('dragme', e.target)){
            fn.activeElm = e.target;

            e.preventDefault();

            fn.startPos = {x : e.pageX, y : e.pageY};

            var lastPos = {x : fn.activeElm.getAttribute('data-posX'), y : fn.activeElm.getAttribute('data-posY')};
            if(lastPos['x'] && lastPos['y']){
                fn.transPos = {x : parseFloat(lastPos['x']), y : parseFloat(lastPos['y'])};
            }else{
                fn.transPos = {x : 0, y : 0};
            }
            fn.pos = {x : fn.transPos['x'], y : fn.transPos['y']};
            fn.loop();

        }
    },
    handleMove : function(e){
        if(!fn.activeElm)
            return;
        fn.pos = {x : fn.transPos['x'] + e.pageX - fn.startPos['x'], y : fn.transPos['y'] + e.pageY - fn.startPos['y']};
    },
    handleStop : function(e){
        if(!fn.activeElm)
            return;
        fn.activeElm.setAttribute('data-posX', fn.pos['x']);
        fn.activeElm.setAttribute('data-posY', fn.pos['y']);
        fn.activeElm = null;
    },
    addStep : function(move){
        var arr = fn.moveSteps;
        arr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
        arr.push(move);
        fn.moveSteps = arr;
    },
    loop : function(){
        if(!fn.activeElm)
            return false;
        fn.requestAnimFrame(fn.loop);

        fn.addStep(fn.pos['x']);
        fn.animate();
    },
    animate : function(){
        var arr = fn.moveSteps;
        var rotaSpeed = arr[arr.length-1] - arr[0];
        // The Math.min- and max are there, so we can be sure the angle won't rotate more than 90° and -90°
        var rotation = 'rotate(' + Math.max(Math.min(90, rotaSpeed), -90) + 'deg)';

        if(!fn.activeElm)
            return;
        var obj = fn.activeElm.parentNode.style;
        obj.webkitTransform = obj.MozTransform = obj.msTransform = obj.OTransform = obj.transform = 'translate(' + fn.pos['x'] + 'px, ' + fn.pos['y'] + 'px) ' + rotation;
    },
    requestAnimFrame : function(callback){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame && window.requestAnimationFrame(callback) || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(callback) || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame && window.mozRequestAnimationFrame(callback) || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame && window.mozRequestAnimationFrame(callback) || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame && window.msRequestAnimationFrame(callback) || 
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    },
    hasClass : function(classname, obj){
        return new RegExp(' ' + classname + ' ').test(' ' + obj.className + ' ');
    }
}
fn.init();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzvSt/1/)

- What I do: I calculate how much the mouse has moved during the last 15 mouse moves, and then set the rotation-degree to that value. So when the mouse moves fast, the span between the 15 mouse moves will be big and the box rotation will therefore be big. When the mouse moves slowly, the span will be smaller and the box rotation will not be as big as before.

But the result doesn't look realistic, especially not when you're moving the mouse fast. I think the function Math.sin is needed to make a more realistic 'ease' in the rotation, as the div moves.
I have no idea how I can calculate this physics, so if anyone has an idea, sources, examples, formulas, what ever or just know the name of the effect it would be great.

//Best regards

Comment: For the record, air pressure isn't the reason why the bottom of the box seems "pushed back"; it's because of inertia -- the bottom of the box wants to stay still while the top wants to move, so the bottom gets left behind because it resists motion.

Comment: Try using a sine function to "ease" your speed, and scale it to a range smaller than (-90,90) (like (-50,50).  I gave it a try and it seems to look better.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [**2D Rigid Body Dynamics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics).

Consider use a **physics engine** to accomplish your desired effect with much less effort and great results.

Notice that [Google Gravity](http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google-gravity/) uses [Box2Djs](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/), a physics engine, port of Box2DFlash to JavaScript. If you look at the page's code you'll find how to setup Box2djs properly.

With Box2d you'll be able to setup the world and objects properties(like gravity, friction) and other physics properties.

Here follow a sample of code present in Google Gravity for deal with Box2d:

```
// init box2d

worldAABB = new b2AABB();
worldAABB.minVertex.Set(-200, -200);
worldAABB.maxVertex.Set(window.innerWidth + 200, window.innerHeight + 200);

world = new b2World(worldAABB, new b2Vec2(0, 0), true);

// Get box2d elements

elements = getElementsByClass("box2d");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    properties[i] = getElementProperties(elements[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.style.left = properties[i][0] + 'px';
    element.style.top = properties[i][1] + 'px';
    element.style.width = properties[i][2] + 'px';
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', onElementMouseDown, false);
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', onElementMouseUp, false);
    element.addEventListener('click', onElementClick, false);

    bodies[i] = createBox(world, properties[i][0] + (properties[i][2] >> 1), properties[i][1] + (properties[i][3] >> 1), properties[i][2] / 2, properties[i][3] / 2, false);

    // Clean position dependencies
    while (element.offsetParent) {
        element = element.offsetParent;
        element.style.position = 'static';
    }

}
```

This piece of code is just to help you find the code that matters. Study the code of Google Gravity carefully to learn how to use Box2djs to create your desired effect.

If you decides to use a physics engine you might prefer [Box2dWeb](https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) instead of Box2Djs because it is updated and stored in a single js file.

Implement the `realist effect` by your own is hard and demands more than a simple use of sine or cosine. Maybe there's some sort of visually similar effect but, again, the realist effect it's harder to accomplish without apply good physics simulation.

[2D Rigid Body Dynamics](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec21.pdf) - MIT OpenCourseWare

Answer (score 1):

Without any real simulation, I've done something customizable that take the speed of the last 2 moves to set the angle of your div.

```
this.drag = function (elem, e)  {
    //
    //ROTATION
    //
    //If there's an end animation I kill it.
    endAnimation.stop();
    //Saving the mouse position
    history.push(e);
    //When we have positions to compare
    if(history.length > 1){
        if (history.length > 2) {
            history.shift();
        }

        var dX = history[0].clientX - history[1].clientX; // Delta
        var tAngle = Math.ceil(angle * -dX);  // Angle to reach       
        var rotation = 'rotate('+ tAngle +'deg)';

        $(elem).css({WebkitTransform: rotation});
        $(elem).css({'-moz-transform': rotation});
        $(elem).css({transform: rotation});
    }
}
```

With that, you can change the angle variable to increase or decrease the angle.

I've also added some inertia on drop, using another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443526/jquery-ui-drag-easing-inertia)

You can see result here http://jsfiddle.net/Spope/tzqwx/